# Jinja2 block that is unreadable

Tags: flask

I have a block of Jinja2 (used in Sceptre/CloudFormation). It is not readable in my opinion, but I can't find any way to clean it up to improve it.

```jinja2
{% set args = "--kubelet-extra-args '--node-labels=nodegroup=" + sceptre_user_data.node_group_name %}

{% if sceptre_user_data.node_labels != "None" %}
  {% set args = args + "," + sceptre_user_data.node_labels %}
{% endif %}

zone=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone)

{% if sceptre_user_data.cni_custom_network == "Yes" %}
  {% set args = args + ",k8s.amazonaws.com/eniConfig=pod-netconfig-$zone" %}
{% endif %}

{% if sceptre_user_data.taints != "None" %}
  {% set args = args + " --register-with-taints=" + sceptre_user_data.taints %}
{% endif %}

{% set args = args + "'" %}

eval "/etc/eks/bootstrap.sh ${EKSClusterName} {{ args }}"
```

I tried using `join` filters although that seemed to make it worse.

(This has nothing to do with Flask, but is all about Jinja2 obviously. But there appears to be no Jinja2 tag.)

Comment: This question lacks any indication of what the code is intended to achieve. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question, including a title that summarises the *purpose* of the code. We want to know **why** much more than **how**. The more you tell us about [what your code is for](//meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1226), the easier it will be for reviewers to help you.  The title needs an [edit] to simply [**state the task**](//meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/2436).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I refactored like this:

```jinja2
{% set node_group_name = sceptre_user_data.node_group_name %}
{% set node_labels = sceptre_user_data.node_labels %}
{% set taints   = sceptre_user_data.taints %}
{% set cni_custom_network = sceptre_user_data.cni_custom_network %}

...

do_bootstrap() {
  {% set args = "--kubelet-extra-args '--node-labels=nodegroup=" + node_group_name %}

  {% if node_labels != "None" %}
    {% set args = args + "," + node_labels %}
  {% endif %}

  {% if cni_custom_network == "Yes" %}
    zone=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone)
    {% set args = args + ",k8s.amazonaws.com/eniConfig=pod-netconfig-$zone" %}
  {% endif %}

  {% if taints != "None" %}
    {% set args = args + " --register-with-taints=" + taints %}
  {% endif %}

  {% set args = args + "'" %}

  eval "/etc/eks/bootstrap.sh ${EKSClusterName} {{ args }}"
}

do_bootstrap
```

I would still welcome feedback from anyone who knows a Jinja2 trick that might help that I don't know.